# Create Visual Studio style Options/Settings Dialog

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I am currently in the process of improving my options dialog for a winforms application.  At the moment I am using a tab control.

I would like to create a form/dialog for settings that is similar to Visual Studio's.  How is this done?  I can see a treeview like control on the left hand side but what control are they using to display each of the options pages, it doesn't appear to be a tab control. I would like to be able to build the controls for each of the settings at design time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look to me like `UserControl`s.  I can't say how exactly they implement it, but it would be simple enough to build a `UserControl` for each option type and swap out the current control when the tree view selection changes.  In your designer you would simply have the `TreeView` and a parent panel to host the `UserControl`s.  At runtime you would perform the swap.

Comment: Thanks @Ed S.  I see what you mean.  That seems kind of long winded but I guess that's what they do.  I think I can manage the part of swapping out the usercontrols at runtime. But how do I bind to the settings?  Sorry I cant seem to mark your post as helpful, not enough rep!

Comment: Native dialog templates, not available in Winforms.  UserControl is certainly close enough.